# How to make 3d collada model solid in scenekit

Tags: physics, scenekit, collada

I am working for a game in which i have a man which can move under the cave and when this man collide with cave walls it cross the wall and come outside,therefore i want the walls of cave should be static so that the man should not come out when hit the walls.How can i apply physics on my collada model in scenekit?Here is my model image[image]

Here is my code

```
 scene = SCNScene(named: "game.scnassets/UpdatedTunnel/second.dae")!
   let Tunnel = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("skpC1CB", recursively: true)!
   TunnelNode.addChildNode(Tunnel)
    var shape:SCNPhysicsShape?
    if let geometry = TunnelNode.geometry{
        shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry, options: nil)
        var nodePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: shape)
        TunnelNode.physicsBody = nodePhysicsBody
        nodePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()



    }
```

Comment: you may need to use a convex hull type for physic shape

Comment: i make shape convexhull but the problem is same it not working...

Comment: check your category, collision, and contact bit masks

Comment: i set categoryBitmask and collisionBitmask but it is not accepting any thing its behaving same .....bhammm

Comment: could you send a pic of what it looks like with physics visualization on?